# Django - Python - How to include STATUS CODE in response using JsonResponse?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is my code, that let users input their ID and Name to check if they are in a list of something.

```
def some_api(requests):
    try: 
        **do something**
        return HttpResponse('Your name is in the list') #Response 302 CODE FOUND NOT 202
    except:
        return JsonResponse([{ ID       : 123,         #Response 203 CODE EMPTY NOT 202
                               Name     : ABC,         #with information for users to double check
                               Content  : []           #their params
                              }])
```

As always, when I return `HttpResponse` and `JsonResponse`, it is always the 200 CODE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With django-rest-framework you can add status like below:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def some_api(request):
  try:
     **do something**
     return Response('Your name is in the list', status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
  except:
    return Response({"id": 123, "Name": "Abc", "Content": []}, 
                     status=status.HTTP_203_NON_AUTHORITATIVE_INFORMATION)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the JsonResponse as said in your question.

```py
JsonResponse({'status':'false','message':message}, status=500)
```

For `HttpResponse`, just use one of its subclasses:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses.

Note that if you're using DRF, you should go for Ochom Richard's answer, `rest_framework.response.Response` object.